# c# WPF GridView Columns Showing Empty Items

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a WPF program that will go through a list of items and put each of those listed items into a list view.

However when I add the items to the list view the columns just show up empty (but highlight when I mouse over the list view so the items are being added)

I was just wondering why the values are not showing up in the columns.
Also if it helps I know that "SetData" has values in it because I did a step-into and watched the values be added.

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <ListView x:Name="LIV_SetList">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <!--Each column will display a specific property of the set, its name, code and total number of cards-->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Set Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SetName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Set Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SetCode}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Number Of Cards" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SetCount}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**.cs**

```
 // Shove all the data just gathered into a Set Overview, and put that set overview into a list item which is then added to the listview 
                    Classes.SetOverview SetData = new Classes.SetOverview { SetName = SetReader["name"].ToString(), SetCode = TempCode, SetCount = SetSize };
                    LIV_SetList.Items.Add(SetData);
```

**SetOverview Class**

```
public class SetOverview
    {
        //This Is Used On The Main Window To Display Information Regarding A Given Sets Name Code And Number Of Cards
        public string SetName;
        public string SetCode;
        public int SetCount; 
    }
```

Comment: try manually typing the xaml columns and column names then your list of items to the listview

Comment: Please add your XAML and .cs into the question so we can better assist you with this. I believe the question may need a little more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without know how you define the SetOverview class but if it's just a class with 3 string members (SetName, SetCode, SetCount) make sure they are defined as public properties (with get and set) not just regular strings. for example:

```
public class SetOverview
{
    public string SetName { get; set; }
    public string SetCode { get; set; }
    public string SetCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for that it worked a treat, although what does the {get; set;} actually do as opposed to just a regular string? I've seen it before in a couple of school tasks the class got walked through but never got an explanation as to what it changes over just having the variable and a ;.

Comment: The get and set make it a property as opposed to a field/member of the class. XAML generally deals with properties. If you want more explanation check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties